# Count the number columns using NOT NULL in a case statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need some help with my query...I am trying to get a count of names in each house, all the col#'s are names.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    House#, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN col#1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    COUNT(CASE WHEN col#2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    COUNT(CASE WHEN col#3 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count
FROM 
    myDB 
WHERE 
    House# IN (house#1, house#2, house#3) 
GROUP BY 
    House#
```

Desired results:

```
house 1 - the count is 3
house 2 - the count is 2
house 3 - the count is 1
```

...with my current query the results for count would be just 3's

Comment: Use `sum` instead of `count`

Comment: Please post DDL,DML Of the tables involved and dont post images.Having this info helps others to quickly repro your issue and asnwer better.Below is some sample which might help you understand.  

**--sample data**  
`create table t1
(
id int
)

insert into t1
values
(1),
(2),
(1)
`    
**my current query/what i have tried:**   
`select id,count(*) as cnt from
t1
group by id`  

**my current result:**  
`id cnt
1  2
2  1`

**my expected result:**
`id cnt
1  2
2  1
1  2`

Comment: NULLs are NOT included in COUNTs. Just loose the CASE expressions and you should be good.

Comment: The reason i am using nulls is each of the houses have multiple col#'s and each col# could have a name...or not. Some houses can have multiple different names and i am looking for the number of times a different name occurs in a house and so I use the null to create a counter...hope that helps clarify my question.

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT` by design doesn't count `NULL` values.

```
SELECT House#, 
       COUNT(col1#) + COUNT(col2#) + COUNT(col3#) AS count
FROM myDB 
WHERE House# IN (house#1,house#2,house#3) 
GROUP BY House#;
```